# Twilio API PHP : Retrieve only the latest SMS message received from a certain mobile number (FROM)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Here's the code I use to retrieve SMS messages received to a specific number on a specific date:

```
$receivedMessages = $twilio->messages
                      ->stream(array(
                        "to" => $activeTwilioNumber,
                        "dateSent" => $dateToday,
                        , 50
                      );
```

Now, I would like to retrieve only the last message sent from all FROM numbers, not all messages.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can retrieve the latest message sent from a number by [filtering the list with the "from" attribute and limiting it to 1 message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources). Something like:

```php
$receivedMessages = $twilio->messages
                      ->stream(array(
                        "from" => $fromNumber,
                        , 1
                      );
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Phil. The thing is I am trying to get the latest message of all the FROM numbers that sent a message in a certain time period, not just one FROM number. Any idea on how to achieve that? I am considering building arrays with the data retrieved from $receivedMessages and then sorting it out, but I doubt this is the best way.

Comment: The only filters available when listing messages are `to`, `from` and `dateSent`. So you will need to list all the messages and sort them yourself.